# Laravel 5.4 CRUD DELETE Method not working, there is no reaction on clicking DELETE

Tags: laravel

After clicking on DELETE, there is no reaction, absolutely nothing happens. I am using HTML Forms, that's why I used,                      @method('DELETE'). I had similar problem with edit, after using @method(PUT), edit is working properly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 align-self-start">
        <a class="btn btn-light"  href="/listings/{{$listing->id}}/edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
        <form action="{{action('ListingsController@destroy', [$listing->id])}}" method="POST">
            <?= csrf_field()?>
            @method('DELETE')
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/dashboard">Delete</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Destroy Function:

```
 public function destroy($id)
 {
    $listing = Listing::find($id);
    $listing->delete();
    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Contact Deleted');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/dashboard">Delete</a>
```

to

```
<a type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" href="/dashboard">Delete</a>
```

You should add `submit` otherwise it will not submit the form.

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Its recommended to use a  instead of :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```